# Share attributes/ variables between classes python

Tags: python, class

```py
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Base created")
        a = "baseclass"

class ChildA(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        Base.__init__(self)
        b = "child a"

class ChildB(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ChildB, self).__init__()
        c = "child b"
        print(a)
        print(b)

ChildA()
ChildB()
```

```
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: What makes you think `ChildB` should have access to `ChildA.b`?

Comment: @blhsing that sounds a bit rude, the OP is clearly a beginner.

Comment: you have to use `self.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is that you're trying to access local variables instead of instance attributes.

Here's how you should do it:

```py
class Base():
    def __init__(self):
        print("Base created")
        # Note that you should use `self.a` instead of `a`
        self.a = "baseclass"

class ChildA(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        Base.__init__(self)
        # Use `self.b` instead of `b`
        self.b = "child a"

# Did you forget to inherit from `ChildA`?
class ChildB(ChildA):
    def __init__(self):
        # The `super()` call can be simplified
        super().__init__()
        # Use `self.c` instead of `c'
        self.c = "child b"

        # Access the instance variables using `self.`
        print(self.c)
        print(self.b)
        print(self.a)


ChildA()
ChildB()
```

From the console output:

```
Base created
Base created
child b
child a
baseclass
```

Comment: forgot self. , this worked.